# Clarifications on @capacitor/filesystem Directory enum

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am working with `@capacitor/filesystem` package and struggle with picking directories for specific purposes. The package has the following enum defined:

```
export declare enum Directory {
    /**
     * The Documents directory
     * On iOS it's the app's documents directory.
     * Use this directory to store user-generated content.
     * On Android it's the Public Documents folder, so it's accessible from other apps.
     * It's not accesible on Android 10 unless the app enables legacy External Storage
     * by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `application` tag
     * in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
     * It's not accesible on Android 11 or newer.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    Documents = "DOCUMENTS",
    /**
     * The Data directory
     * On iOS it will use the Documents directory.
     * On Android it's the directory holding application files.
     * Files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    Data = "DATA",
    /**
     * The Library directory
     * On iOS it will use the Library directory.
     * On Android it's the directory holding application files.
     * Files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled.
     *
     * @since 1.1.0
     */
    Library = "LIBRARY",
    /**
     * The Cache directory
     * Can be deleted in cases of low memory, so use this directory to write app-specific files
     * that your app can re-create easily.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    Cache = "CACHE",
    /**
     * The external directory
     * On iOS it will use the Documents directory
     * On Android it's the directory on the primary shared/external
     * storage device where the application can place persistent files it owns.
     * These files are internal to the applications, and not typically visible
     * to the user as media.
     * Files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    External = "EXTERNAL",
    /**
     * The external storage directory
     * On iOS it will use the Documents directory
     * On Android it's the primary shared/external storage directory.
     * It's not accesible on Android 10 unless the app enables legacy External Storage
     * by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `application` tag
     * in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
     * It's not accesible on Android 11 or newer.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    ExternalStorage = "EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
}
```

From what it says, Android 11 or newer can only utilize Data, Library, Cache, and External folders.

---

From my understanding, I can use and I need to store the following types of content:

- `Library/Data/External`: System files (database files)
- `Data/External`: User-uploaded data (images, videos, files, uploaded to the application)
- `?`: Downloads from my application (backup export)

---

So, I have the following questions:

- Which directories should I use to store these types of data and why?
- Also, what is meant by shared/external? SD card?
- What's the difference between `External` and `ExternalStorage`? Both were introduced at the same time (since 1.0.0). Do they end up pointing to different locations?

---

For external downloads from my application (backup export) I tried to use `Documents` directory (`Download` folder in it, specified via a separate `path` parameter), and it seems to be working for me, even though my phone is `Android 12 (Funtouch OS_10.5)`. I am not sure if it will also be working for other users on other systems.

I also tried checking out [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) on that topic, but it seems to not be bound to these enum values.

Comment: Hey, I'm also facing this issue, did you find any answer? I'm trying to create an app that has private content that only the app should be able to access.

Comment: Sadly, I have not :c

Comment: Still no answer here? Trying to store some png's locally and then submitting the uri to Google maps as a custom marker iconUrl.  No luck though.  Can't even seem to get anything from a hard-coded assets/icon.png file.  Laaame

Comment: Nope, still no solution, I ended up duplicating this question on GitHub: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/1869